# div#ID not being appended to document by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I inherited a client website, and I am not a developer or jQuery developer.

On the client website, at bottom right is supposed to be a `div#scrollUp` which contains an image of an up arrow and scrolls the browser up to the top of the page when clicked.

The following script is designed to handle the scrolling up behaviour:

```
! function(a, b, c) {
    a.fn.scrollUp = function(b) {
        a.data(c.body, "scrollUp") || (a.data(c.body, "scrollUp", !0), a.fn.scrollUp.init(b))
    }, a.fn.scrollUp.init = function(d) {
        var e = a.fn.scrollUp.settings = a.extend({}, a.fn.scrollUp.defaults, d),
            f = e.scrollTitle ? e.scrollTitle : e.scrollText,
            g = a("<a/>", {
                id: e.scrollName,
                href: "#top",
                title: f
            }).appendTo("body");
        e.scrollImg || g.html(e.scrollText), g.css({
            display: "none",
            position: "fixed",
            zIndex: e.zIndex
        }), e.activeOverlay && a("<div/>", {
            id: e.scrollName + "-active"
        }).css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: e.scrollDistance + "px",
            width: "100%",
            borderTop: "1px dotted" + e.activeOverlay,
            zIndex: e.zIndex
        }).appendTo("body"), scrollEvent = a(b).scroll(function() {
            switch (scrollDis = "top" === e.scrollFrom ? e.scrollDistance : a(c).height() - a(b).height() - e.scrollDistance, e.animation) {
                case "fade":
                    a(a(b).scrollTop() > scrollDis ? g.fadeIn(e.animationInSpeed) : g.fadeOut(e.animationOutSpeed));
                    break;
                case "slide":
                    a(a(b).scrollTop() > scrollDis ? g.slideDown(e.animationInSpeed) : g.slideUp(e.animationOutSpeed));
                    break;
                default:
                    a(a(b).scrollTop() > scrollDis ? g.show(0) : g.hide(0))
            }
        }), g.click(function(b) {
            b.preventDefault(), a("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, e.scrollSpeed, e.easingType)
        })
    }, a.fn.scrollUp.defaults = {
        scrollName: "scrollUp",
        scrollDistance: 300,
        scrollFrom: "top",
        scrollSpeed: 300,
        easingType: "linear",
        animation: "fade",
        animationInSpeed: 200,
        animationOutSpeed: 200,
        scrollText: "Scroll to top",
        scrollTitle: !1,
        scrollImg: !1,
        activeOverlay: !1,
        zIndex: 200
    }, a.fn.scrollUp.destroy = function(d) {
        a.removeData(c.body, "scrollUp"), a("#" + a.fn.scrollUp.settings.scrollName).remove(), a("#" + a.fn.scrollUp.settings.scrollName + "-active").remove(), a.fn.jquery.split(".")[1] >= 7 ? a(b).off("scroll", d) : a(b).unbind("scroll", d)
    }, a.scrollUp = a.fn.scrollUp
}(jQuery, window, document);
```

The script above has comments:

```
 scrollup v2.1.1
 Author: Mark Goodyear - http://markgoodyear.com
 Git: https://github.com/markgoodyear/scrollup
 Copyright 2013 Mark Goodyear.
 Licensed under the MIT license
```

In the header is `jQuery.scrollUp();`, but the problem is that there is no `div#scrollUp` produced, meaning the up arrow is not present on the page.

I can't see anywhere in the theme file a mention of `#scrollUp`, so I assume the Javascript block above, plus the header running `jQuery.scrollUp();` is supposed to insert the `div#scrollUp` - is that correct?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the

```
$(function () {
    $.scrollUp({
        zIndex: 2147483647   
    });
});
```

on the `<script>` tag of your page, and let see whats happen.

Instead showing 3rd party plugin javasript code, you better show the code inside your page.

Comment: I've searched the online webpage source code and there is no mention of a div with ID `scrollUp`. Does that mean it isn't present?

Comment: you can search the div based on ID using chrome developer console or firefox firebug.. or just run this code `$('#scrollUp').size()` if the output is > 0 then the div is exist

Comment: I receive a response of 1. I will try the JS in your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the up arrow is not visible.

Comment: then if you got 1, try to test this code `$('#scrollUp').attr('style','z-index:999999;border:5px solid red;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:visible')` then check on your page if the div appear or not on left top side..

Comment: I found the element in code inspector now, don't know why not before. The code in my question has `display: none;` for some question. Removing that attribute makes the arrow appear.

Comment: maybe the listener jsut wrong, did you scroll the page to most bottom? or your page is not scrollable?